# Unable to start embedded tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Our Spring boot application is throwing the following error when I try to run it as a Spring Boot Application. (Right Click -> Run As -> Spring Boot Application)

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
        at com.dhboa.trex.TRexApplication.main(TRexApplication.java:14)
    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:98)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:378)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:155)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
        ... 7 more
  ..........
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter]: Factory method 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 145 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig;
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:82)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:63)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.<init>(XmlMapper.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiate(BeanUtils.java:78)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:514)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration.java:84)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2b9ded.CGLIB$mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter$0(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2b9ded$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$911122bf.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f2b9ded.mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 146 more
```

The same source is working on a different machine. I tried Force updating the maven dependencies once again but didn't result in anything. Also, war file is being built properly when I do maven install.

**Update**
[image: Dependency heirarchy]

**Extract of POM**

```
<project>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>        
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <activiti.version>5.17.0</activiti.version>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.64</tomcat.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
        <version>${activiti.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.icegreen</groupId>
        <artifactId>greenmail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Email Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dhboa.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>data-utils</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
                    <classifier>apt</classifier>
                    <version>3.6.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Well it looks like a library version mismatch. First thing to do is to run **mvn dependency:tree** to see what Maven is instructed to pull in by both your project and as transitive dependencies. You're looking for jackson related dependencies.

Comment: It seems a jackson library version mismatch. How are the environments configured?

Comment: @both, thank you. I've updated the post with dependency hierarchy.. I don't see any version mismatch. Perhaps you can see any.. Thank you..

Comment: could you show the pom.xml?

Comment: added the pom details..

Comment: Is the tomcat version the same on the two different machines?

Comment: I haven't installed a tomcat in my eclipse on my vm because the embedded tomcat is used isn't it. I update my Pom in my initial post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the issue with jackson-databind jar. On your jar screenshot it can be seen that the jar with version 2.4.5 is getting resolved & used while the method **withDefaultPrettyPrinter** has been introduced with version 2.6.0 of jackson-databind jar only. Pls correct the jar version to resolve the issue.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig.
withDefaultPrettyPrinter(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter;)
Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig;
```

Comment: Worthy to note is that version 2.4.5 is pushed in as a transitive dependency of spring-boot. So "correcting the jar version" might be upgrading spring-boot to a newer version, or manually including the jackson dependencies in the project pom to override any transitive dependencies.

Comment: I had not included compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf") this dependency so I was facing issue